# Accessing fields in Thymeleaf with custom Getters/Setters

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to use an entity, an instance of `Order`, in my Thymeleaf template. An `Order` has a few fields that can be nullable, namely a `CustomerOrderReference`. To explicitly handle the nullability, the getter of the field returns `Optional<CustomerOrderReference>` (a value object is being used), the setter, however, takes a nullable `CustomerOrderReference`:

```java
public class Order {
    [...]
    private CustomerOrderReference customerOrderReference;
    [...]

        public Optional<CustomerOrderReference> getCustomerOrderReference() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(customerOrderReference);
    }


    public void setCustomerOrderReference(CustomerOrderReference customerOrderReference) {

        this.customerOrderReference = customerOrderReference;
    }
```

I am binding the `Order` in a thymeleaf template:

```java
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <label th:text="#{order-creation.customer-order-reference}"
                                   class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                                <input th:field="*{customerOrderReference}" th:value="*{customerOrderReference}" class="form-control"
                                       data-test-id="customer-order-reference" id="customer-order-reference"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And I am using a custom Parser/Printer to handle the values being sent back and forth:

```java
public class CustomerOrderReferenceFormatter implements Parser<CustomerOrderReference>,
    Printer<Optional<CustomerOrderReference>> {

    @Override
    public CustomerOrderReference parse(String text, Locale locale) {

        return CustomerOrderReference.from(text).orElse(null);
    }


    @Override
    public String print(Optional<CustomerOrderReference> object, Locale locale) {

        if (object.isPresent()) {
            return object.get().getValue();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Doing so results in a template parsing error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source to convert from must be an instance of [net.xxx.order.model.order.CustomerOrderReference]; instead it was a [java.util.Optional]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:187) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:904) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
[...]
```

I know what the error means -- but I am not sure about how the error occurs:
As far as I know, registered custom formatters will be used to handle a type (like the `Optional<CustomerOrderReference>`. This isn't the case, though.

Does Thymeleaf/Spring MVC look at the field type (`CustomerOrderReference`) and is therefor unable to handle the `Optional<CustomerOrderReference>` return type?

How can I change this behaviour (work with different return types for getters and setters/fields)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have your data in an `Optional` container. That a special container class to hold the value which could be null with protection from the `NullPointerException`.

Thymeleaf can't handle such values by default. I believe you simply shouldn't use `Optional` in getters of DTO objects which you use in Thymeleaf templates.

Try to handle `null` values before the creation of these DTO objects or inside a template with elvise operator `${somparent?.somechild}`.

Comment: I am glad that you are trying to help, but can you re-read the question?
1. I am trying to handle the Optional values with a Formatter
2. I specifically asked about how I can change thymeleaf default behaviour (I WANT to work with the Optional here)
3. I am not working with DTOs here.

Comment: I don't think you can change this behavior. At least I never heard about such functions in Thymeleaf.

Comment: As far as i know, this is mostly Spring MVC code that influences the thymeleaf behaviour...